# Change NCWidgetDisplayMode programmatically in IOS10 Widget

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

I am looking to programmatically change the height of a today extension. As the iOS10 SDSK introduced `NCWidgetDisplayMode` I am trying to use it to programmatically change the height of my `preferredContentSize`.

I have implemented `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange`:

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.Compact) {
        self.preferredContentSize = maxSize
    }
    else {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: 280)
    }
}
```

I want the widget height to expand when a `UIButton` is pressed :

```
@IBAction func multiplybyonethousand (sender: AnyObject) {

    if self.extensionContext?.widgetActiveDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.Compact {

        self.widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(.Expanded, withMaximumSize: CGSizeMake(0, 300))
    }
}
```

However when I run my code, the height of the today extension does not change and the console gives me the following error:

```
2016-11-05 14:24:29.425697 todayextension[28590:7222420] No active animation block!
```

I have tried to call `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange` inside an animation block:

```
@IBAction func multiplybyonethousand (sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.extensionContext?.widgetActiveDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.Compact {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(.Expanded, withMaximumSize: CGSizeMake(0, 300))

            }) { (completed) -> Void in
             //Do Stuff
            }
        }
}
```

But I still get the `No active animation block!` error message. Is there a way to programmatically expand a today extension view in iOS10 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `iOS 10`, `Show More/Show Less` button is automatically provided in the `Today's Extension`. So height of the `widget` is handled automatically through `NCWidgetDisplayMode`. You don't need to provide any explicit button for handling the widget's height.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
        self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
    }
}
```

Implement `NCWidgetProviding` protocol's method:

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if activeDisplayMode == .expanded {
            preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: 300)
    } else {
        preferredContentSize = maxSize
    }
}
```

In, `iOS 8` and `iOS 9`, you need to explicitly handle widget's height. In `iOS 10`, it is not required.

You can refer to https://github.com/pgpt10/Today-Widget on `Today's Widget` implementation in `iOS 8`, `iOS 9` and `iOS 10`.